# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, typescript

Eu quero pegar o "src" de uma imagem do html mas fica mostrando esse erro. Estou tentando fazer da seguinte maneira

```js
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-sombraFase1',
  templateUrl: 'sombraFase1.html',
})
export class SombraFase1Page {
  src: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    var srcuu:any = (<HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById("sol")).src;
  }
  ionViewDidEnter(){
    console.log(this.src);
    
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ion-header>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="bgcSombra" padding>
  <img src="assets/img/cabecalho.png" alt="Cabeçalho" id="cabecalho" (click)="voltarHome()">
  <div class="divDica">
    <img src="assets/img/audio.png" class="dica">
    <img src="assets/img/msgDica.png" class="msgDica">
  </div>
  <div class="imgsGame">
    <img src="assets/img/Sol.png" id="sol">
    <img src="assets/img/lua.png" id="lua">
    <img src="assets/img/Sol-sombra.png" id="solSombra">
    <img src="assets/img/lua-sombra.png" id="luaSombra">
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Ele fica retornando null, como posso resolver esse problema ?

Comment: o erro ocorre na linha `var srcuu:any = (<HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById("sol")).src;`?

Comment: Não ocorre na linha do Constructor

Comment: Até fiz uma resposta, mas fiquei na dúvida quando alterar a linha para `var srcuu:any = (<HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById("sol").src);`. Não sei se isso está correto, mas me pareceu válido... ou não?

Answer (score 0):

Como você está tentando acessar um elemento baseado em seu id, você poderia usar o *decorator* do Angular [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) ao invés de usar JavaScript puro.

#### sombraFase1.html

```
<ion-content class="bgcSombra" padding>

  ...

  <div class="imgsGame">
    <img #minhaImagem src="assets/img/Sol.png" id="sol">

    ...

  </div>
</ion-content>
```

#### sombraFase1.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

...

export class SombraFase1Page {
  @ViewChild('minhaImagem') minhaImagem;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    console.log(this.minhaImagem); //visite seu elemento usando this.minhaImagem
  }

}
```